# Using Global Variables for Validators in Angular [Angular 10]

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, validation, angular-material

I'm making a form with validators in Angular 10, and I am using the Validators.min() method for my form...

instead of me hardcoding the Validators.min('100') value in the form, how can I make a global variable that sets the value to be 100 and I can reuse this variable across components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By saying global I guess you mean something you can import/inject and use in another services/components. The easiest way would be to have some enum placed in a shared directory e.g `app/shared/configs/validator.ts` and then you would export it as follows

```
export enum ValidatorConfig {
  MIN = 100;
  MAX = 1000;
}
```

then you would import it everywhere it is needed

`import { ValidatorConfig } from 'src/app/shared/configs/validator';`

and use it like this

`Validators.min(ValidatorConfig.MIN)`

Comment: Seems strange to use an Enum for parameters... A class with static attributes would do the same, but easier to understand.

Comment: Don't think there is anything hard to understand here and this approach is widely used in Angular ecosystem. But sure, class with static attributes  would work too.